# Counstructor, making object

Tags: c++

I am working on a small homework on C++ and i have small problem. The error is the following when I try to run the program:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00E0193B in ConsoleApplication6.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
```

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

I tried to debug my program and i noticed, that program run out, when i try create object c1. Method v_setR doing good, but v_setCenter giving this error. I don't have idea what i do bad, but i think it's simple mistake. Thanks for help :)

It's main cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Punkt.h"
#include "Okrag.h"
#include "math.h"

/*double Circle::d_distance(Point pcOther)
{
    double d_result = sqrt(
        (pd_point.d_getX - pcOther.d_getX)*(pd_point.d_getX - pcOther.d_getX)
        + (pd_point.d_getY - pcOther.d_getY)*(pd_point.d_getY - pcOther.d_getY)
        );
    return d_result - d_r;
}*/

Circle::Circle(double dX, double dY, double dR)
{
    v_setR(dR);
    v_setCenter(dX, dY);
}

void main()
{
    Point p1(1, 2);

    Circle c1(5,4,4);

    //std::cout << c1.d_distance(p1);

    system("pause");
}
```

It's point.h and circle.h

```
class Point
{
    friend class Circle;
    //friend double d_distance(Point &pcOther);

public:
    Point() { };
    Point(double dX, double dY) : d_x(dX), d_y(dY) { };

    // Setters
    void v_setX(double dX) { this->d_x = dX; }
    void v_setY(double dY) { this->d_y = dY; }
    void v_setPoint(double dX, double dY) { this->d_x = dX; this->d_y = dY; }

    // Getters
    double d_getX() { return d_x; }
    double d_getY() { return d_y; }

private:
    double d_x, d_y;
};

class Circle
{
    friend class Point;

public:
    Circle();
    Circle(double dX, double dY, double dR);

    // Setters
    void v_setR(double dR) { d_r = dR; }
    void v_setCenter(double dX, double dY) { pd_point->v_setPoint(dX, dY); }
    // Getters
    double d_getR() { return d_r; }
    Point *d_getCenter() { return pd_point; }
    //double d_distance(Point &pcOther);

private:
    Point *pd_point;
    double d_r;
};
```

Comment: You don't allocate any memory for `pd_point`. Why do you have that as a pointer?

Comment: I think that you can define point as a struct with public values for the coordinates. No need of a pointer to point in circle class also.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because `pd_point` has not been allocated. This would be a lot easier if instead you removed the pointer. By removing the pointer you could write:

```
Circle::Circle(double dX, double dY, double dR)
    : pd_point(dX, dY),
    d_r(dR)
{
    v_setCenter(dX, dY);
}
```

You would also have to change the function using `pd_point`:

```
void v_setCenter(double dX, double dY) { pd_point.v_setPoint(dX, dY); }
```

Or you could keep this a pointer (if your assignment requires this for example). That would require you to allocate memory for the pointer before you call `v_setCenter(double, double)` and read up on implementing a copy constructor/destructor/(move).

[Something like this.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0888465007e8606)

Answer (score 1):

you are not allocating any memory for the pd_point pointer. therefore trying to access pd_point->v_setPoint(dX, dY); is faulty.

in order to fix the problem you can allocate memory for your pointer in the constructor of circle as follows:

```
Circle::Circle(double dX, double dY, double dR)
{
    this->pd_point = new Point();
    v_setR(dR);
    v_setCenter(dX, dY);
}
```

I do have to say though, that you would benefit from using an initializer list. there are better ways of initializing